# set size of image resource on the fly with call setImageResource

Tags: android, image, android-layout, imageview, android-drawable

I have a drawable that I would like to render in different sizes on the fly, as opposed to setting the size in layout file. How might I do that? I am referring to the call

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decode the resource as a bitmap with a resolution (and other options) specified, then tell the ImageView to show the bitmap:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.outHeight = XXXX;
options.outWidth = XXXX;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);

imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```